# Why this list comprehension is not giving proper output

Tags: python, list

Consider this code snippet

```
x=[1,2,1,3]
b=[]
b=[a for a in x if a not in b]
print(b)
```

The expected output is [1,2,3] but I am getting [1,2,1,3]  Where as

```
  x=[1,2,1,3]
    b=[]
    for a in x:
        if a not in b:
            b.append(a)
    print(b)
```

This gives proper output. Could you please let me know the reason for this? I am an amateur python programmer

Comment: Also, only have one of each number in a list use `set(list)`

Comment: Thanks @BuddyBob I have tried for an hour and was confused and hence asked for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet does not give the expected output because of the scope of `b`. Within the comprehension, `b` is an empty list (`[]`). So, the first snippet is just testing `a` for membership in `[]`, which is always `False`. None of the elements in `x` are elements of `b` until after the assignment (`b = [a for a in x if a not in b]`) is complete.

This may be demonstrated in the following code, which demonstrates what's going on behind the scene.

```py
x = [1, 2, 1, 3]
b = []
tmp = []
for a in x:
    if a not in b:
        tmp.append(a)

b = tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Ruth. I understood the difference now.

Answer (score 4):

```
b=[]
b=[a for a in x if a not in b]
```

is equivalent to

```
b=[a for a in x if a not in []]
```

or

```
b=[a for a in x if True]
```

or

```
b=[a for a in x]
```

Because until the second line is fully completed `b` keeps it's value from the first line, i.e. the list comprehension is computed with current value of `b`, then its result is reassigned to `b`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Julien.  I thought for every iteration, b list would be updated even in the 'if' condition.